# Dynamically assign column headers and rows and access each cell in C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, matrix, tabular

I need an output like this:

[image]

The column headers must be dynamically assigned.
The rooms are dynamically assigned too.

I want to access each cell(marked X) by getting the room name and the date.

```
for example:
    - Room 1, 1/2/2014
    - Room 2, 1/3/2014
    - Room 3, 1/2/2014
    - Room 4, 1/4/2014
```

So far, I have assigned the items to a C# list but haven't bound them as column headers.

Also, each cell must be clickable.

Comment: What kinda app is this, MVC?  If so whats the view engine you're using?  I assume you dont want to do all this client side in an Ajax request?

Comment: @cobolstinks a Web app. definitely not client side..

Answer (score 0):

Well if you're using the razor view engine you could do something like the following.

In your controller that is gonna render your page:

```
public ActionResult SomeAction(){
     var yourlist = SomeMethodThatReturnsYourList();
     return("yourViewName",yourList);
}
```

Then in your view something like this:

```
@model List<yourObjectTypes>
<table>
   <tr>
      /** empty 0,0 table cell **/
      <th></th>

      /** renders the table headers today - today + 4 days) **/
      @for (var i = 0;i<5; i++){
      <th>
        @DateTime.Now().AddDays(i).ToShortDateString();
      </th>
      }
   </tr>

   /** main loop renders rest of the table **/
   @Model.foreach(m=>{
      <tr>
          <td>m.RoomName</td>
          /** loop over the 5 days per every room in the list and put an x where appropriate **/
          @for(var x = 0;x<5;x++){
            @if(m.ShortDateString == @DateTime.Now().AddDays(x).ToShortDateString()){
               <td>X</td>
            }
            else{
               <td></td>
            }
          }
      </tr>
   });

</table>
```

I wrote that in this editor so it might have syntax issues.  I always reference this article when confronted with razor syntax questions.  The code above should at least be enough to guide you in the right direction.  Good luck.

[Razor Cheat Sheet](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx/)